# Couldn't check out xlsx file from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I noticed that the reading can be done without the check out.
I don't need the check out and check in. Looks ok?  Its working also without $ExcelWorkBook.save(). How it is possible?
But There are instances of Excel even after running the script below:
What I am missing?

```
$ExcelWorkBook.Close()
$ExcelObject.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkBook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
#Remove-Variable Excel
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Do you think the order can cause this issue?

Maybe something is closing before something else? ($ExcelWorkSheet, $ExcelWorkBook, $ExcelObject, $ExcelObject.Quit())

```
$ExcelWorkBook.CheckIn() 
#$ExcelWorkBook.Close($false) #Alwaty fails so I removed it
$ExcelObject.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkBook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

In order to change data in the sheet I need to use the save() or just check in? Maybe the save is causing to this problem?

I have a script that connect to SharePoint online ,read information, modify cell and save. The issue is that most of the times its not working and I get a message that check out is failed. After restart to the computer sometimes its working. I think something is leaved open. What I am doing wrong???

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointSiteURL #-Credentials $PSCredentials
        $ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($SharePointSiteURL) 
        $ExcelObject.Workbooks.CheckOut($SharePointSiteURL)
        $ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("VIP List")
```

Change some data

```
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.CheckIn()

$ExcelObject.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelWorkBook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

[image]

It failed even when there is no instance of Excel in the task manager

Tried to add $ExcelWorkBook.Close($false)
But still the check out is not working.
I thought after restart all connections will closed.
Please need help
What about disconnecting after Connect-PnPOnline?

Comment: What status does the workbook show when you can't check it out? Maybe Excel sometimes does `Quit()` before it's able to finish `CheckIn()`? Or maybe `CheckIn()` fails for some other reason?

Comment: The document status in the web is not checked-in. And i can open it and edit via the web.
In PS I get:
This document cannot be checked out.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ExcelObject.Workbooks.CheckOut($SharePointSiteURL)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I am running the steps one by one. It fails when I get to the check out

Comment: Do you really need to check out the workbook?

Comment: Yes. It does not work without it when working with online document

Comment: @NirCarmona You will need to make sure the document is checked in before you can check it out. For example, you could discard your previous checkout, or skip the checkout process altogether since it is already checked out to you.

Comment: Its not the case. I tried to not using the check out and I got this message:
We cannot do that for you because the file is no longer checked out

Comment: @NirCarmona No, try checking the file status *in your script* before attempting to check out or check in

Comment: How can I check the file status?